# nodemon : File cannot be loaded. The file is not digitally signed

Tags: nodemon

I'm trying to run a nodemon server and its bringing out this error:

```
nodemon : File C:\Users\1040 G3\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 
cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\1040 
G3\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 is not digitally signed. You      
cannot run this script on the current system.
```